# Get Data from Application user with costum objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an Application User with a many-to-many relationship to Categories.
I've tried to implement this relationship according to EntityFramework latest guides.

```
[Table("AspNetUsers")]
    public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {

        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            ApplicationUserCategories = new HashSet<ApplicationUserCategory>();
        }

      public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserCategory> ApplicationUserCategories { get; set; }


[Table("ApplicationUserCategories")]
    public class ApplicationUserCategory
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }

    }

 [Table("Categories")]
    public class Category
    {

        public Category()
        {
            ApplicationUserCategories = new HashSet<ApplicationUserCategory>();
        }
      public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserCategory> ApplicationUserCategories { get; set; }
    }


public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUserCategory> ApplicationUserCategories { get; set; }
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUserCategory>(
            build =>
            {

                build.HasKey(t => new { t.ApplicationUserID, t.CategoryID });
            });

        }
    }
```

Now, inside a controller, I want to be able get the Categories whom ApplicationUser has.
I want to do something like this:

```
public IActionResult GetData()
        {
            var categories = _userManager.GetCategories;
        }
```

Comment: If you are using .Net core you need to use the Dependency Injection to inject the DbContext and later call the DbContext from the controller something like: var categories = _context.GetCategories().ToListAsync();

Answer (score 0):

You can create many-to-many relationship by adding below codes in `OnModelCreating` method :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserCategory>(
    build =>
    {

        build.HasKey(t => new { t.ApplicationUserID, t.CategoryID });
    });

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserCategory>()
        .HasOne(pc => pc.ApplicationUser)
        .WithMany(p => p.ApplicationUserCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.ApplicationUserID);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserCategory>()
        .HasOne(pc => pc.Category)
        .WithMany(c => c.ApplicationUserCategories)
        .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.CategoryID);

}
```

Then apply migration (`add-migration name`) and update database `update-database` in visual studio's package manager console .

After that , you can query the current user's related categories by :

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var userID = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

    var categories = _applicationDbContext.Users.Where(p => p.Id == userID)
                        .SelectMany(p => p.ApplicationUserCategories)
                        .Select(pc => pc.Category).ToList();

}
```